# Do the set S={$s \in Q: s \in [0, 1$]} have volume zero?

Tags: general-topology

Here, I wonder what is a good way to use the epsilon delta definition or converging sequences to show that the set S containing quotients on [0,1] have/does not have volume 0, (i.e. whether there exist a **finite** number of intervals which union contain all of S such that the **sum** of length of all intervals is less than any $\epsilon > 0$ you fix). I believe it more likely does not have volume 0 from my intuition . I am lost on where to start the proof.

Does the idea of closure of S play a part in this proof? and how?

Also, is it possible to prove this using pigeonhole principle involving infinite rationals in one interval?

Comment: I clarified my question by saying that the the UNION of such finite interval contain all of S.

Comment: The rationals are dense in the reals, hence the volume should be the same as the volume of the interval $[0,1]$. But maybe, I miss something, I am no expert in topology.

Comment: I wrote an answer, I think you have downvoted. I need to know what I got wrong if you downvoted, otherwise please read the answer.

Comment: How exactly is the definition with $\epsilon$ ? If we must have a finite number of intervals that we can make arbitary small, the given set cannot have volume $0$. But if it is meant that for a fixed $\epsilon>0$, we must have finite many intervals covering the set, obviously the volume would be $0$. What is the exact definition ?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I did not downvote your answer, and unfortunately it is now deleted so I cannot read.

Comment: I will undelete it, have a look.

Comment: I believe the definition of $\epsilon$ is just "true for any $\epsilon>0$", same as the one used in the definition of continuity and uniform continuity.

Comment: "For every $\epsilon>0$ we can cover the set with finite many intervals with length $\epsilon$" ? In this case, every finite interval (and any subset of such an interval) would have volume $0$ , hence also your set $S$.

Comment: Correction of "we can cover the set with finite many intervals with length $\epsilon$" to "with sum of interval of length $\leq \epsilon$".

Comment: @LHC2012 OK, this makes it different. Doesn't that mean that we can only cover discrete sets this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, closure does play a part, if you are going for *finitely* many intervals to do the covering.

The point is, if $I_1,...,I_n$ are intervals that covered $S$, say $S \subset \cup_{i=1}^n I_i$, then we can assume that the $I_i$ are closed (doesn't change their length and increases the union anyway), so that $S$ is contained in the finite union of the closed sets , which will remain closed (by finiteness of how many sets we are taking a union of). Thus, by definition of closure, we get that $[0,1]$,  the closure of $S$, is contained in the union of these intervals.

Now, by monotonicity and subadditivity of the length of intervals under taking their union, we get that the sum of the lengths of the intervals is at least $1$. Thus, under taking only finite intervals for covering, we cannot get volume zero.

If you allow infinitely many intervals, then the union is *no more closed*, for example, and then one checks that we can narrow the lengths as we want to make the volume zero.

---

Suppose $I_i$ are closed intervals such that $[0,1] \subset I_i$. We have the usual notion of length : if $I = [a,b]$ where $b \geq a$ then $l(I) = b-a$.

Now, we define the length of a finite disjoint union of intervals, by taking the sum. Thus , for example $l([0,1] \cup [2,3]) = 1+1 = 2$.

When we take the union of two intervals, either they overlap so some length is lost in the union, or the union is disjoint so retains the length. In short, it is a standard argument (extended to more intervals) to show that $l(A \cup B) \leq l(A) + l(B)$ for $A,B$ disjoint union of intervals, by checking how much each interval overlaps with another and so on.

Next, we get by induction that $l(A_1 \cup ... \cup A_n) \leq l(A_1) + ... + l(A_n)$.

Monotonicity of length is clear : if a set contains another, it must have larger length : look just at intervals, and extend to a union of intervals again.

Now, using the definition, we get $l([0,1]) \leq l(I_1) + ... + l(I_n)$ because $[0,1]$ is contained in $\cup I_i$, so we are using both monotonicity and subadditivity here.

Comment: Thank you, but can you elaborate more on the monotonicity and subadditivity and how that will cause the sum of length to be at least 1? I am learning multivariable calculus that only touches upon analysis, so my understanding in sets is not good.

Comment: I will do that. But can you justfiy the downvote? If you can, it would be nice. Is  it because I did not explain the subadditivity? Did I get some detail wrong?

Comment: Again, I was not the one who gave the downvote, but sure I will give an upvote.

Comment: Thank you once again : I knew you had not downvoted, but I am very paranoid about getting downvoted, and always like to improve my answer and please whoever that person was.

Comment: I have completed the editing, kindly have a look. I cannot elaborate too much, because I will go into too much algebra, while I am sure an explanation of the kind mentioned is shorter  and captures the gist of the argument.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I will look through it soon since I am busy right now. If I accept your answer, it means I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\lambda(\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]) < 1$, where by $\lambda$ I mean the volume of the set (as (sort of) defined in the comments to the question.

This would mean that we can cover $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$ by finitely many intervals $I_1,\ldots, I_n$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda(I_j) < 1$ too, and we can assume these are closed intervals (as $\lambda([a,b])=\lambda((a,b))=b-a$ etc.) but then $[0,1]\setminus (\bigcup_{j=1}^n I_j)$ is a non-trivial open subset of $[0,1]$ that misses the dense set $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$, which is a contradiction. So $\lambda(\Bbb Q \cap [0,1])=1$.

Comment: I think you should say $[0,1]\setminus (\cup_{j=1}^n I_j)$..........+1

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide an effective answer, just think of the volume of the complementary set, which is the whole interval but a countable union of zero-measure sets, hence the complementary set has measure one (i.e., the set you are looking for has measure zero).

Comment: Hello AZM. What I am looking at is not measure zero, but volume zero. There is a distinction between them in the sense that all countable sets are measure zero, but they are not necessarily volume zero because volume zero means the number of intervals you can "trap" S in must be finite.